# NService 2.6 to consume Nservice 3.0 contracts

Tags: nservicebus

We are in a situation where one of our componentes is developed in Nservice bus 2.6.
We are at the moment working on developing a new componet using NSB 3.2 which will be consumed from the old service. 
We are having issues sharing contracts from NSB 3.2 to NSB 2.6 component.
We can not right away migrate old system to NSB 3.2 since it will be lot of work.
does anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 2):

Especially if you're trying to use the [Unobtrusive Mode](http://andreasohlund.net/2011/12/15/support-for-running-nservicebus-in-unobtrusive-mode/) for your 3.2 message contracts, you're going to run into NServiceBus 2.6's hard requirement on referencing NServiceBus.dll Version 2.6 for access to the IMessage interface.

Of course, 2.6 has no concept of IEvent and ICommand either.

One solution would be to have dual projects for your 3.2 message contracts assembly.

```
MyPublisher.Events-2-6.csproj
MyPublisher.Events-3-2.csproj
```

Each project would reference the same C# files, but the 2.6 version would reference the 2.6 NServiceBus.dll, while the 3.2 version would reference either the 3.2 version, or if using Unobtrusive, perhaps include an additional file to define assembly-specific IEvent, ICommand, IMessage interfaces. Of course you could also use conditions on namespace names or some other metric to define these and skip that step.

Then the last thing you might need is some `#if` blocks in your message contracts to specify the differences between versions, for example:

```
#if NSBGT3
    public void MyEvent : IEvent
#else
    public void MyEvent : IMessage
#endif
    {
        // properties
    }
```

Full disclosure: I have not tried this yet myself, I have just been thinking this is how I would go about it. Try it out and publish some messages, then inspect them and see what goes into message XML about the types that message applies to. This will give you a better idea of if NServiceBus 2.6 will accept them properly, especially where concerns about polymorphic message handling come into play.  Of course you'll want to test with a 3.2 client and a 2.6 client as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend linking the class files of the old system in the solution of the new system, that way they'll be compiled with the newer NServiceBus binaries and you'll avoid the version conflicts.